# Is there anyway to know where you are in an array? Swift?

Tags: swift

I currently have an array of strings. The user will scroll down, and I want to know how far they went down the list.

Is there anyway to do this, without using the indexPath.row feature from tableView/collectionView AND without knowing the string? (String is currently random data pulled from my database)

```
var name = ["jfiwojf", "awjefoeij", "awjfioe", "awjefoi"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check your table view property [indexpathsforvisiblerows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614885-indexpathsforvisiblerows). This will return an array with the index of the cells that are visible to the user at the time you call that property. You just need to check the which element of your collection is represented by the last index returned from it.

If are using a collection view you can check its [indexpathsforvisibleitems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618020-indexpathsforvisibleitems) property. Note that the result of this method is not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to do some things like set an index

You can do it like so

`var index = 0`

```
func didTapped(index: Int) {
   index = index 
}
```

Then you call when your user selected a row or select an item.